# UISplitViewController and OpenGLES

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, uisplitviewcontroller

How do I render an OpenGLES object inside the Detail View controller of a UISplitViewController application for the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real trick to this, you simply need to create a UIView that is backed by a CAEAGLLayer, like you would for any other OpenGL ES rendering, and place that view within your detail view controller. You then treat the detail view controller like you would any other in that situation, commanding the controller to swap out the 3-D models on changes in selection for your left-hand list.

If you want an example of this, you can download the source code of my Molecules application from [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules), where I display a molecular model in an OpenGL ES hosting view within the detail portion of the split view controller, then change the displayed model in response to selections from the other portion of the split view.